# Detect when anything in a column is changed, google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Basically I want any edit within an entire column in google sheets to trigger an email. I've spent a long time looking but have been unable to find anything that addresses this issues. I want to automatically send a form anytime a value in an entire column is changed, using an OnEdit trigger. I have it working for when a specific cell changes, but cannot seem to get it for any value in the column. Currently I have this:

```
function autoEmailTest(e) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Project Status");

var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(); // "B2"
var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();

if (rangeEdit == "B2")    // stops changes from every cell triggering emails
   MailApp.sendEmail("xyz@email.com", "ACTION REQUIRED", "link here");
```

}

I've tried using

```
'Project Status'!B:B
```

as in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation), but since it seems to want a direct reference to a cell I'm not sure how to go about this. 
Additionally, but not required, if anyone knows how to set the trigger to either include or exclusively happen when the cell colour is changed that would be helpful.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Anything in terms character change. The current plan is to have the column named "status", filled with "incomplete" as default, and when changed to "complete" automatically send an email to the person in charge.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. I did not realize you could index on A1 notation. Changing it to:

```
 if (rangeEdit[0] == "B") {
   do stuff 
}
```

checks for everything in column "B" and stops spam from any cell change.